# Execute mocha tests one by one

Tags: mocha.js

I have 3 test files named test1.js, test2.js and test3.js in my test folder. I want to execute it sequentially by test1.js, test2.js and test3.js. This is because the output of test1.js is the input for test2.js and the output of test2.js is the input for test3.js. Currently the tests are starting it's own order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following this steps:

In your index.html add the files in the correct order. In your case you need to add `test1.js,`test2.js`and`test3.js`.

In test1.js, you have to add some variable **beforeEach**, for example:

```
//test1.js
beforeEach(function() {
  this.someVariable = 'foo';
});

describe('test1', function() {
   //Your tests  
});
```

In your test2.js you can get the variable.

```
//test2.js
var foo = this.someVariable;
```

I think this approach will help you.